# Maintaining transparency explained

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, transparency, import

What does it means to "*maintain (or not) Transparency*" in Photoshop when placing it in another program like InDesign?

Answer (score 8):

Take the image of the blue circle below as an example. "Maintaining transparency" means when it is placed in a document, the checkered parts around the circle will remain see-through.

[image]

[image]
*transparency maintained*

If transparency is NOT maintained, the document bounds of the blue circle file will be visible (the white part). The edges around it will no longer be see-through.

[image]
*transparency not maintained*

Answer (score -1):

In Design has transparency option so I think you don't need to take care of maintaining transparency. you can apply transparency to the object in In Design.

Comment: Wrong answer for this question. InDesign's transparency can only be applied to entire objects. It has nothing to do with "maintaining" the transparency in a placed file.